# Windows 2003 Dual Nic Gateway server

Tags: windows-server-2003, routing, remote-access, gateway

I'm trying to configure a Windows 2003 server with two interfaces as a gateway. I'm looking to have this server as a gateway to another network which has an internet gateway.

Nic 1: 172.16.0.0 (internal Network and DNS,DHCP server on same box)
Nic 2: 192.168.0.0 (Interface to network with Internet Gateway)

Ive got "Routing and Remote Access" installed and configured as below:

```
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
      0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.1.254     192.168.1.93     10
    127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0        127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1      1
   172.16.1.0    255.255.255.0       172.16.1.1       172.16.1.1     10
   172.16.1.1  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1     10
172.16.255.255  255.255.255.255       172.16.1.1       172.16.1.1     10
  192.168.0.0      255.255.0.0    192.168.1.254     192.168.1.93      1
  192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0     192.168.1.93     192.168.1.93     10
 192.168.1.93  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1     10
192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255     192.168.1.93     192.168.1.93     10
    224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0       172.16.1.1       172.16.1.1     10
    224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0     192.168.1.93     192.168.1.93     10
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255       172.16.1.1       172.16.1.1      1
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255     192.168.1.93     192.168.1.93      1
Default Gateway:     192.168.1.254
```

I cant seem to work out how to get traffic coming in on 172.16.x.x interface to pass traffic to 192.168.x.x interface

I also have IPForwarding enabled.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: NO!  Bad Sysadmin!  Don't deploy a new system that's already almost EoS.

Comment: Apologies I should have mentioned this is purely for testing purposes.

Comment: Same comment, really.  There's little to no point in "testing" on such an old, obsolete platform.  Use 2008 R2 at the very least... then [you can use RRAS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469714.aspx), not to mention a platform that isn't all but dead and buried.

Comment: @HopelessN00b I dont see how you can say there is no point in "testing" when you really dont know what or why im "testing". So please refrain from posting unless you would like to help with the question at hand.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable [ICS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324286/en-us) for the internet-facing interface.

You can also download a [trial version](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2012-r2) of Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 and use it for your tests (for 180 days, after which you have to reinstall everything).

Comment: ill try that asap and let you know how I get on.

Comment: I have added ICS but I still cant seem to get the servers on the internal LAN to communicate through the ICS server.